# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type but everything seems fine to me

Tags: c

So I did some digging about this error and I seem to be getting it for no reason (obviously that can't be the case though so I decided to ask)

In my .h file I declare

```
typedef struct setCDT *setADT;
```

and in my initialization I have

```
struct setCDT{
    setElementT x[MaxVal];
    int len;
};

setADT setNew(){
    setADT set;
    set=(setADT)malloc(sizeof *set);
    set->len=0;
    return(set);
}
```

I change the values around later in the code and if I need to post that I can but from what I understand this has to do with how I set up the structures.

In my driver program I have `setADT A = setNew();` but when I call `printf("%d", A->len);` it throws this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the struct setCDT{...} part declared?  It should be in a .h file that the driver program #includes, otherwise the compiler won't know what the contents of the struct are supposed to be, and will give you an 'incomplete type' error.

Comment: Where are SetElementT and MaxVal defined?

Comment: can you post whole source?

Answer (score 3):

Without actually seeing the code, analysing this is difficult but I'm guessing the file that contains the line:

```
printf("%d", A->len)
```

is not the file in which you have the `struct setCDT` definition; rather it's only including the `.h` file with the

```
typedef struct setCDT *setADT;
```

If you want to manipulate the member variables in other files you will need to put the `struct setCDT` definition in the `.h` file.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the issue

```
 set=(setADT)malloc(sizeof *set);
```

It should be

```
 set=(setADT)malloc(sizeof(struct setCDT));
```